# How to reload table content only whenever a database record is added/changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have a PHP page which contains 2 tabs `Entry` and `View`. From the `Entry` tab I can insert data in a database and on my `View` tab I have an HTML `table` which displays the data. There is also a provision to insert data from my `View` tab as well.

I want to reload my `table` every time some new data is added. I tried this using jQuery but the problem is that it reloads my entire page and sends me back to my `Entry` tab, even if I have inserted the data from my `View` tab. Can anyone tell me if there is any provision to reload just HTML table every time I add new data to the database and stay on the same tab from wherever I have added my data?
Here is what I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var refresher = setInterval("update_content();", 60000); 
})

function update_content(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "main.php",
        cache: false, 
    }).done(function( page_html ) {
        // alert("LOADED");
        var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
        newDoc.write(page_html);
        newDoc.close();
    });   
}
```

main.php code goes here-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Logsheet-Dhanraj & Co.</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="css/table_edit.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="css/styleinputcontainer.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="css/footable.standalone.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="css/footable.core.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui\jquery-ui-themes-1.11.4\jquery-ui-themes-1.11.4\themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />



  </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">

           <div class="panel panel-info">

             <div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="panel-title ">Logsheet-Dhanraj
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="panel"><a href="http://www.google.com">&times;</a></button></div>
             </div><!--panel heading-->


             <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#Entry" data-toggle="tab">Entry</a></li>
                      <li ><a href="#View" data-toggle="tab">View</a></li>
                   </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Entry">

                             <div class="container-fluid">

                                <form id="dataentry" action="insert_data.php" method="post">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                </div><!--empty row-->

                               <div class="row">



                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                  <label for="Date">Date</label></br>
                                  <input type="text" name="date" id="date" autocomplete="off"/>
                                 </div><!--col 1-->


                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                   <div class="input_container">
                                   <label for="Clientname">Client Name</label></br>
                                   <input type="text" name="clientname" id="clientname" onkeyup="autocomplete_client()" autocomplete="off" />
                                   <ul id="clientlist_id"></ul>
                                   </div><!--inputcontainer client-->  
                               </div><!--col 2-->

                               <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                  <div class="input_container">
                                  <label for="Staff">Staff</label></br>
                                  <input type="text" name="staff" id="staff" onkeyup="autocomplete_staff()" autocomplete="off"/>
                                  <ul id="stafflist_id"></ul>
                                  </div><!--inputcontainer staff-->
                               </div><!--col 3-->

                                 </div><!--row1-->

                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="Matter">Matter</label></br>
                                    <textarea rows="4" cols="60" name="matter" id="matter" ></textarea>
                                    </div><!--matter col-->
                                 </div><!--row2-->

                                  <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <button id="sub" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                                    <button id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                                    </div><!--button col-->
                                 </div><!--row3-->


                              </form>
                               <div class="container-fluid">
                               <br />
                              <div class="row">
                              <br />
                                  <p id="result"></p>
                               </div>
                             </div><!--result-container-->

                             </div><!--entry container-->

                        </div><!--entry tab-->


                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="View">
                          <div class="container-fluid" id="view_result"><br />
                             <form id="viewentry" action="view_insert.php" method="post">

                            <div class="inputWrapper">
                            <div class="row">

                             <div class="col-md-3">
                              <div class="input_container">
                            <label for="Client Name">Client Name</label><br />
                            <input type="text" name="viewclientname" id="viewclientname" onkeyup="viewautocomplete_client()" autocomplete="off"/>
                            <ul id="viewclientlist_id"></ul>
                             </div>
                           </div>

                             <div class="col-md-3">
                              <div class="input_container">
                             <label for="Staff Name">Staff Name</label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="viewstaff" name="viewstaff" onkeyup="viewautocomplete_staff()" autocomplete="off"/>
                            <ul id="viewstafflist_id"></ul>
                             </div>
                           </div>

                              <div class="col-md-4">
                             <label for="Matter">Matter</label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="matter" name="matter" />
                             </div>

                              <div class="col-md-1">
                                <br />
                                <button id="add" class="btn btn-info">Add New</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-1">
                                <br />
                                <button id="can" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                              </div>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                         </form>
                         <p id="done"></p>
                             <div class="row">
                           <br /><br /><label for="Search">Search:</label>
                           <input type="text" id="filter" /><br><br>
                         </div>
                         <div id="divGrid">
                             <table class="footable" data-filter="#filter" id="tableresult">
                               <thead>

                                <th>Client name</th>
                                 <th>Staff name</th>
                                 <th>Matter</th>
                                 <th> Delete</th>
                              </thead>

 <?php
include('db.php');
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM  newdata ORDER BY client_name ASC");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$clientname=$row['client_name'];
$staff=$row['staff'];
$matter=$row['matter'];

?>
<tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="edit_tr">

<td class="edit_td" >
<span id="client_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $clientname; ?></span>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $clientname; ?>" class="editbox" id="client_input_<?php echo $id; ?>" /&gt;
</td>

<td class="edit_td">
<span id="staff_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $staff; ?></span> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $staff; ?>" class="editbox" id="staff_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</td>

<td class="edit_td">
<span id="matter_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $matter; ?></span> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $matter; ?>" class="editbox" id="matter_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</td>



<td class="delete_td"><input type="button" id="del" class="btn btn-danger" value="&times;"></input></td>

</tr>



<?php
}

?>

</tbody>
  <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
    <th>                       </th>
     <th>
        <div class="pagination pagination-centered"></div>
     </th>
    <th>             </th>
    <th>             </th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
                           </div>
                        </div><!--view tab-->


                    </div><!--tab content-->

             </div><!--panel body-->


</div><!--panel info-->

</div><!--container-->
</header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/footable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/footable.filter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/footable.paginate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/view_autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/footable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/insert_submit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/view_insert.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/selected_row.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/table_edit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/deletefootable_row.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {  
        $( "#date" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
        });
      });

</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var refresher = setInterval("update_content();",60000); // 60 seconds

})

function update_content(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "main.php", // post it back to itself - use relative path or consistent www. or non-www. to avoid cross domain security issues
      cache: false, // be sure not to cache results
    })
      .done(function( page_html ) {
       // alert("LOADED");
    var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
    newDoc.write(page_html);
    //alert(page_html);
    newDoc.close();

    });   

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as per your need do a ajax call

Comment: ohk you already doing it ..i dint see that .. than whats the problem ???

Comment: the problem is that it reloads the entire page and redirects me back to my entry tab even if i have inserted the data from my view tab

Comment: What are you getting in page_html variable ?
I mean entire HTML or what kind of HTML are you getting ?

Comment: What is the content returned by `main.php`? You should write that page so it either returns JSON which you can then use to update the table, or it should generate the HTML of an entire new table with the content added so you can simply replace the current one. The former is by far the more efficient of the two.

Comment: sorry ,i didn't get you...but i am getting the page reloaded and i am being send on my entry tab which is my starting tab @Ali

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can u please elaborate the later one or please help me with its implementation in my code thats provided above

Comment: Please provide me the value of page_html variable which you are getting from Ajax.

Comment: @everyone my home page is main.php ...this is the page that contains entry and view tab

Comment: @payal_suthar to do that we need to see the code of `main.php`, as myself and others have already asked.

Comment: datatables can be good here

Comment: just say what you echoed (echo) in `main.php`  or just paste your main.php code here

Comment: @Ali my page_html is returning me the same main.php page contents

Comment: Yes I want to know that content.

Comment: guys , i have provided with my main.php code

Comment: thank you guys ...got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method does exactly this:

```
function update_content() {
    $('#divGrid').load('main.php #divGrid>table');
}
```

Comment: ..with the code above i am able to reload the table but it does not allow to edit my table or delete my rows